# NetBeans 12.1 Xdebug 3.0.2 break points not breaking

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I am trying to debug a Jooomla web site on the following system:

- NetBeans 12.1
- Xdebug 3.0.2
- PHP 7.4.14
- nginx 1.18.0
- CentOS 8

Xdebug configuration from this file `/etc/php.d/90-xdebug.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

When I start debugging NetBeans shows that it is connected to Xdebug but it does not stop on breakpoints.

Also I don't see any `/var/log/xdebug.log` file at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard client_port is 9000. This is the standard setting in netbeans options for php debugger. (Tools -> Options -> Tab 'PHP' -> Debugging: Debugger Port).
Either you change the xdebug.ini or check whether the Debugger Port is set to 9003.

Comment: No at xdebug 3.0.2 default is 9003 and anyway is set also 9003 on netbeans